# Initializing Error: How to create a multi dimensional zero array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

This code is written in C++ to make a multi dimensional array but it gives an initializing error. The size of array should be given by input console by the user and so it is not constant value. What is the problem and what is the solution? Thanks a lot.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int A , B ;
    cout << "A: " << endl;
    cin >> A ;

    cout << "B: " << endl;
    cin >> B ;

    int data[A][B] = {{0}};

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is you can't use run-time values to specify the size of an array that way. If you really want to use a C-style array, you could choose a max size and allocate that, and then take the size the user wants to use, and only use that much of it. You could also allocate a buffer of the correct size and then index into it ala C, and free the buffer when done, but these techniques are more like using C in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The size of array should be given by input console by the user and so it is not constant value.

This is not possible in C++. A suitable replacement for using arrays is using `std::vector`. You can use:

```
int A = 10, B = 4;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> data(A, std::vector<int>(B, 0));
```

If you are using a pre-C++11 compiler, you'll need to have a space between the two `>>`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > data(A, std::vector<int>(B, 0));
```

Comment: @AminJaili, elaborate on that, please.

Comment: @AminJaili, I had missed the closing parenthesis.

Comment: there's a typo: vecotr

Comment: It says: "vector is not a member of std"!

Comment: @AminJaili, you need to `#include <vector>`.

Comment: I think you also need a space to avoid a >>     std::vector<std::vector<int> > data(A, std::vector<int>(B, 0));

Comment: @Amin Please don't ever say "it doesn't work". Always describe any errors in detail.

Comment: A vector of vectors is quite different to a 2D array. For one, the data aren't contiguous, and there's nothing to enforce that all sub-vectors have the same length.